# Where does 'stack build PKG' install 'PKG'; how do I isolate the install of 'PKG'?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I'm confused about where `stack build PKG` places the packages it installs. I had thought that, for example

```
mkdir foo
cd foo
stack build PKG_IN_HACKAGE_NOT_IN_RESOLVER
```

would create `foo/.stack-work` and put the specified package there (as if to had been specified as an "extra dependency"); but I seen on `.stack-work` and the package is available globally on my system.

If what I want is an entirely isolated (temporary) Haskell configuration in which to install and use `PKG`, how do I do that?

Comment: If you didn't run `stack init` in `foo`, stack used the "implicit global project" in `~/.stack/global-project` to build that package. The link seems unrelated.

Comment: You might get a better answer if you make the question more concrete, with a concrete package etc.…

Comment: @sjakobi: That's not a bad answer already! So I was just missing `stack init`, without which I'm working in the "implicit global project"; and if I'd done `stack init`, I'd have gotten the behavior I was expecting. (In both cases there is the expected `.stack-work`; but without `stack init`, its the global one.) Correct?

Comment: I'm not sure which behavior precisely you were expecting, so I can't tell. Executables from non-local packages that are part of the current snapshot will be put in the `bin` folder of the snapshot and will be available to other projects that use that snapshot.

Comment: @sjakobi: That building alone "would create` foo/.stack-work` and put the specified package there".

Comment: @sjakobi: I think you've answered this question though. The global project is used if `stack init` (or `stack new`?) hasn't been run, and I haven't entered the directory it creates. If that's all that's the issue here, [I have a relate follow up.](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41429680/656912)

Comment: Does [this section](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#different-databases) help explain where package that is built, is put?

Comment: @sjakobi: I think explaining the bit about how "implicit global project" in `~/.stack/global-project` gets used would constitute an answer (along with mentioning how `stack exec -- ghc-pkg list` can be helpful).