# Workflow for using stack to test Hackage packages (not in Stackage)

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

What is the workflow for using stack to preform an isolated download and install (for testing and experimentation) of a Haskell package that's in Hackage, but not in Stackage?

For example

```
stack new tester
cd tester
# Then add the package PKG to 'extra-deps'
stack build . --force-dirty
```

is not sufficient, and results in errors ("not a module in the current program, or in any known package") when an `import` of part of the package is attempted.

Explicitly building the package (which seems like it shouldn't be necessary) with

```
stack build PKG
```

doesn't work either (resulting in warnings that it "is a member of the hidden package PKG...").

If I instead simply

```
stack new tester --force 
cd tester 
stack build PKG
```

I get the same "hidden package" error when I try to import a component of the package in a `stack ghci` session.

What is the (best practice) workflow for using Haskell stack to create an isolated temporary installation for a working with specific package on Hackage?

Comment: Do you want to experiment on the package itself, as in play around with the package's codebase? Or do you just want that package to be available to write your own code against?

Comment: @MichaelLitchard: I want to be able to use it as if installed, but sandbox it. So, for example, be able to go into ghci (using `stack ghci` and import it and use it there). It seems like the trick (having messed with this a bit) is to use `stack ghci --no-package-hiding`. But may only work for ghci, and also doesn't seem like "best practice" for how to accomplish this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To play with a package that isn't available on Stackage, I usually first try to build it in the global project:

```
$ cd ~/
$ stack build the-package
$ stack ghci
```

If that doesn't work, usually because of missing dependencies or bounds issues, I resort to the following workflow:

```
$ stack new playground
$ cd playground
# In playground.cabal, add the-package to the library build-depends section 
$ stack solver --update-config
$ stack ghci
# Play with the package
```

Comment: Yeah, what throws me is that the workflow at the global level (just build and it works) can't be simply replicated in sandbox (without some file editing). I'd have thought that once one has a sandbox (`stack new tester && cd tester`) it would behave like the global "box" (and `stack build PKG && stack ghci` would be sufficient). Instead the closest one can get to that (without editing files) is to add `--no-package-hiding` to the GHCi invocation, which just seems messy (not to mention obscure).

Comment: Can you please describe precisely, step-by-step, what you did, and where your experience diverged from your expectations?

Comment: I thought I just did. I'm just surprised that I have to have to use `--no-package-hiding` (or the more complex procedure of editing the `.cabal` file manually), especially since neither is necessary at the global level.

Comment: Ok, I reread your first comment, and I think I understand what you mean. To me, the distinction makes sense: In a usual project I care about reproducibility. The global project is just scratch-space to me.

Comment: Still, feel free to [open an issue](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/new)!

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. I'd inverted my thinking, but viewing the global project as scratch has it all making much more sense. So that's really what I should be doing (its a lot simpler). I should probably follow with `stack clean --force` when I'm done (or is there something better?).

Comment: Projects are pretty well isolated from each other, including the global project. But you can `stack clean --force` if you want to prevent any interaction between different packages that you try in the same project.

Comment: Could I perform first steps of your second approach without editing using `stack new --param ... --solver` to modify the `.cabal` file and generate the corresponding changes to the `stack.yml`? If so, what should the argument to `--param` look like to set library build-depends to, say `my-pkg > 0.0.2.2`?

Comment: The build-depends can't be populated via a paramater AFAIK. That would be a pretty hacky approach too. I agree though that this work-flow should be better supported. I think you may find similar feature requests on the issue tracker. Maybe chime in there.